# Why is my MySQLi query returning bool(false)?

Tags: php, mysqli

Why is my MySQLi query returning bool(false)?

```
require_once("LinkDB.php");
$noCommande = $_POST['noCommande'] ;
$req = "Delete From transactions Where no_Commande = ".$noCommande;
require 'config.php';
$connexion = LinkDB::get();

if (!$connexion) 
{

}

if ($connexion)
{   
    $resultat = mysqli_query($connexion,$req) ;
    var_dump($resultat);
    var_dump($req);
}
```

Comment: What datatype is `no_Commande`?

Comment: Integer. I tried to do my query in phpmyadmin, she worked so I don't really understand. Furthermore, the connexion is right because he display my var_dump

Comment: maybe `$noCommande` is undefined. can you check if there is the excpected value?

Comment: echo your query and then run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: I checked and it's the expected value

Comment: @panther the column is not a value from a form.

Comment: My query : `Delete From transactions Where no_Commande = 70214` I tried before to put it in phpmyadmin and it works.

Comment: Also, SQLi warning. use prepared statements to make sure user input is harmless

Comment: @HoareauThomas please check for errors after executing the statement. Then you will see if there is an error in your query.

Comment: is there any record in your table which equals to this id 70214??

Comment: make sure your form is using a POST method and that the element does hold the name attribute for it and with no typos. Error reporting will tell you if there's something wrong. Post your HTML form to be certain. Also make sure your db connection is indeed `mysqli_` and not another API.

Comment: Plus, what's in here `require 'config.php';` ? if that is related to db config, it needs to be before your query, same for `$connexion = LinkDB::get();`

Comment: closing this tab. if you need me, `@` me. moving on...

Comment: All is clear now. I got a acces denied to my BDD

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.
>
> For `DELETE`queries the return false if the query failed.

So that indicates that your query has an error. Call `mysqli_error($connexion));` to see the error message.

Comment: I know but I got false, I should get true

Comment: is there any record in your table which equals to this id 70214??

Comment: @habibulhaq I do not think that delete will return false if there is no record with this id.

Comment: Yes. I tried this @Jens : Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Comment: @HoareauThomas sorry. try my updated anser. Have changed `$reg` by `$connexion`

Comment: like before boolean and not mysqli

Comment: @HoareauThomas have you echod the result of `mysqli_error($connexion);`?

Comment: Yes. I got this `Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given`

Comment: @HoareauThomas Then it looks like your connection is not established. Can you check it please.

Comment: In fact, I got a acces denied to my bdd. I'm on it

Comment: I settled my problem, the file config.php got a bad server name.

Answer (score 0):

`$noCommande` is string, it came from form. You forgot quotes around it.

```
$req = "Delete From transactions Where no_Commande = '" . $noCommande . "'";
```

Or, if you send a number in form, you can change variable type.

```
$req = "Delete From transactions Where no_Commande = " . (int)$noCommande;
```

Comment: `$req = "Delete From transactions Where no_Commande = ".(int)$noCommande;` I do that and it's the same result

Comment: @HoareauThomas: and `print_r ($noCommnade)` returns?